# how to use useTransition for api call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an `Autocomplete` that receives a list of data from an api  And I want to use `useTransition` (like `debounce` function) This is what I did for change input :

```
const [pending, startTransition] = useTransition();


    const handleChange = (value) => {
        setInputValue(value);
        if (value.length > 1 && !pending)
          startTransition(() => {
            props.searchService(
              { phrase: value },
              (status, data) => {
                setOptions(data.result);
              }
            );
          });
        else setOptions([]);
      };
```

If it is typed consecutively, when the typing is finished, the api will not be called until another type is typed separately
Where is my mistake?
What is the best way?

Comment: Not sure if its the best approach but if I had to do, I'll separate API call and translation. Create a state variable and set it in response. Then on its effect, update translation and save it in another variable

Comment: Yes, I did this too, but the problem is still that the api is not called until another character is typed.